# sun.security.provider.SHA2 use 100% cpu and hangs for 5 minutes after a while

Tags: java, spring, jboss7.x, geoserver

I have a strange behaviour and maybe you can help me with it.

The environment is

- jdk_7u40 (Tried with jdk_7u51 with same behaviour)
- debian 6.0 (on windows I have never had this problem)
- jboss 7.1.1
- Geoserver 2.4.x (tried .3 and .4 with same result) which is based on spring framework
- other war modules (not spring-based, but geoserver has some dependencies on them)

The problem is that after a couple of hours that jboss is running, when I try to login to the web interface of geoserver (a POST to the j_spring_security servlet) it took A LOT (4-5 minutes) to land to the welcome page of the application.

Using jstack, I found that there is a thread that consumes 100% of a core for all the time, with and the process keep working here

```
at sun.security.provider.SHA2.lf_S(SHA2.java:162)
at sun.security.provider.SHA2.lf_sigma0(SHA2.java:171)
at sun.security.provider.SHA2.implCompress(SHA2.java:225)
at sun.security.provider.SHA2.implDigest(SHA2.java:118)
at sun.security.provider.DigestBase.engineDigest(DigestBase.java:186)
at sun.security.provider.DigestBase.engineDigest(DigestBase.java:165)
at java.security.MessageDigest$Delegate.engineDigest(MessageDigest.java:576)
at java.security.MessageDigest.digest(MessageDigest.java:353)
at java.security.MessageDigest.digest(MessageDigest.java:399)
at org.jasypt.digest.StandardByteDigester.digest(StandardByteDigester.java:979)
- locked <0x00000006f8c30bb0> (a java.security.MessageDigest$Delegate)
at org.jasypt.digest.StandardByteDigester.matches(StandardByteDigester.java:1099)
at org.jasypt.digest.StandardStringDigester.matches(StandardStringDigester.java:1052)
at org.jasypt.util.password.StrongPasswordEncryptor.checkPassword(StrongPasswordEncryptor.java:99)
at org.jasypt.spring.security3.PasswordEncoder.isPasswordValid(PasswordEncoder.java:204)
at org.geoserver.security.password.AbstractGeoserverPasswordEncoder.isPasswordValid(AbstractGeoserverPasswordEncoder.java:138)
at org.geoserver.security.password.GeoServerMultiplexingPasswordEncoder.isPasswordValid(GeoServerMultiplexingPasswordEncoder.java:75)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:64)
```

Some of you had a similar issue?

**EDIT (with workaround)**

I find out that the problem is related to the CMS garbage collector and to the increase of the permgen space.

**Environment**

The application server is JBoss 7.1.1 with 5 war deployed in it (Geoserver and others). There are shared dependencies among all the wars (with Geoserver too); Java is running with `-XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=36000`

**What happens**

When a full gc is performed, the permgen space is increased *a lot* above the used. After that, the computation of methods in `sun.security.provider.SHA2.*` became very slow.

**How did I solve**

Moving to G1GC garbage collector solved the problem for me (currently I'm using the following options `-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:SurvivorRatio=1 -XX:NewRatio=1 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32m` )

Comment: I found 2 links that report this issue. [JDK bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8023983) and [yellowgrass bug](http://yellowgrass.org/issue/WebDSL/715)

Comment: I've encountered the exact same problem, using JDK7 under Windows.  Total runtime had only been several seconds when it occurred, but the default GC behaved exactly as you describe in your edit.  Unfortunately, the JDK bug you mention says they're not going to bother fixing the bug because they're focusing on JRE signed jars and SSL startup.

Answer (score 0):

I haven not. Can you report the issue on GeoServer own bug tracker? http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS

Comment: I'm waiting to report it as bug in Geoserver, I think it's something "on my side". As soon as I have more information (aka I have a confirm that all the others war in jboss are not the cause) I will fill a bug in geoserver, ok?